# How to set env variable PHANTOMJS_BIN

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

Ok I see this question has been asked before however when I looked at the answers I am still unable to correctly set the environment variable. I tried using the export command but export is not recognized as an internal or external command. Does anyone know how to correctly set the env variable for PHANTOMJS_BIN without using the export command?
The errors I am getting are cannot start PhantomJS
can not find the binary C:\users..
please set env variable PHANTOMJS_BIN
error in plugin gulp-karma
karma exited with code

My node version is 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using Windows. You can set an environment variable as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows). Don't forget to reopen terminal after that.

For `export` command to work you'd need to use some unix terminal emulator, for example Git bash which is included with [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/downloads) (Git/bin/bash.exe).

But the real reason why env var won't work, I suspect, is a misconfiguration of PhantomJS path in Karma's config file, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/69). It seems that at the very beginning of `karma.conf.js` there is an incorrect setting overriding PATH variable:

`process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN = 'node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs';`

If you remove it then the settings from PATH will be used. Or you could hardcode the real location of PhantomJS binary in order not to pollute PATH.

Comment: Definitely check karma.conf.js for incorrect hardcoded `process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN` variable.

Comment: in that file it looks like no base path set. it must be using the settings as you stated

Comment: I was able ot fix the problem by copying the phantomjs.exe into the path it was looking for. However this is not the correct way since it will only work locally. what npm command would I use to fix it globally  Thanks

Comment: How does it know where to look for?

Comment: I'm not even sure

Comment: I'm not sure why that is even a case. What have you used to scaffold the project? Could be an incorrect / outdated template, as is supposed in this [issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/69)